# What does this error mean? java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.time.LocalDate.year

Tags: java, jackson, java-time

I'm trying to make a method, which uses the Json data with jackson library to have a list of objects.
If I run my code, I get the error:

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.time.LocalDate.year accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @5c90e579

Why is it giving me an error about LocalDate even though I have JodaModul in my Code?

```
public static List<Tweet> getTweetsFile() throws Exception{

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().
                    registerModule(new JodaModule()).
                    configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
            
            File path = new File ("C:/Users/PC/eclipse-workspace/hw4/tw.json");

            List<Tweet> myObjects3 =  Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(path, Tweet.class));
    
            return myObjects3;
    }
```

How it looks in my File:

```
[{"date":"2001-12-28","tweetNumber":1,"country":"England","comments":11,"message":"I like to watch anime and reading books","retweets":3,"username":"Isabelle","likes":55},{"date":"2003-05-11","tweetNumber":2,"country":"France","comments":25,"message":"I'm Viatnamese, but I live in France","retweets":30,"username":"Vin","likes":110}..
```

**It's not in the right order like my Object has in their constructor, could that be the reaseon?**

Comment: Do you use the latest version of jackson?

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Module Dependencies_ select the `java.base` module and click _Expose Package..._ button. Enter as _Package_ `java.time`, as _Target module_ `UNNAMED` and select _opens_. Does this fix your issue? But probably the root cause is that you use a too old library that was written for an older Java version. So first check, if your used libraries are up to date.

Comment: I got it now, default constructor was missing and I had a mistake in it and yes I had to use JavaTime for it. Thanks

Answer (score 33):

You can fix this issue on your own.

add `--add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED` as start-argument and it'll work.

Here is the corresponding [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/396)

Comment: if you are on Windows, use `--add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED` for `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable.

Comment: Hi @makson. I have tried with the suggestion by both of you. But still getting same error 
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.time.LocalDateTime java.time.ZonedDateTime.dateTime accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module.


I have tried the answer of creating Bean GsonBuilderCustomizer, but still no luck. Do anyone have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 7):

I used this way and fixed this Problem. Firstly you have to create LocalDateTime Deserializer with the given Date Format in your Json Data.

```
class LocalDateTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer < LocalDateTime > {
@Override
public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
throws JsonParseException {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsString(),
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d::MMM::uuuu HH::mm::ss").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

}

Then create Object of Type GsonBuilder and adapt it with your LocalDateDeserializer.

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Comment: The question is about Jackson, so why Gson answer?

Answer (score 6):

In STS or eclipse **add** the folowing statement in **default VM arguments**

**--add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED**

Default VM arguments path:
Window -> Preferences -> Installed JREs -> select jre -> edit

Comment: if you're testing or trying to initiate a project on your local machine, this is the best solution to fix this problem. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I got this exception with JDK 17 and Gson:

```
Unable to make field private final java.time.LocalDate java.time.LocalDateTime.date accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time"
```

so I used this custom TypeAdapter with null checks:

```
public class LocalDateTimeTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final LocalDateTime localDate) throws IOException {
        if (localDate == null) {
            jsonWriter.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        jsonWriter.value(localDate.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime read(final JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            jsonReader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(jsonReader.nextString()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use this adapter

Comment: Could you please add code maybe as an example

Comment: Example of registering the TypeAdapter:

    static final Gson GSON;
    static {
        GSON = new GsonBuilder() //
                .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer()) //
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY) //
                .setDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd") //
                .setPrettyPrinting() //
                .create();
    }

Comment: Thanks, exactly my case, and it helped, but I didn't quite get the reason why it started happening to me. I upgraded to Java 17, and my JUnit test started failing with those error. There is an answer explaining this, it seems https://stackoverflow.com/a/76002266/2518705 , also this gson ticket https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2485 , and the comments seem clear, however my class doesn't have any `LocalDateTime` fields, so not sure why I had to add this adapter.

Answer (score 2):

From my reading of [this issue](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-databind/issues/3168), the problems that required you to [do the "--add-opens" hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70878195/139985)  or other work-arounds **should be fixed** in current Jackson releases.

So, if you are still finding you need to do this:

1. Make sure you are using a recent Jackson release<sup>1</sup>.
2. If that doesn't help, raise a Jackson issue which sufficient specificity to allow the Jackson developers to figure out where this instance of the problem is occuring.

The "--add-opens" approach will work, but it is not a good solution.  The good solution is to *help* the developers to fix the problem by reporting it.

---

<sup>1 - I can't give you a specific release because it is not clear from the issue tracker or release notes *precisely* when the problem(s) were fixed.   But 2.14.0 or later seems like a good bet, based on the date of the issue closure.</sup>

Comment: Thits a gson issue not jackson (?)

Comment: This is a Jackson issue.  The question is about Jackson and so is my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue when I was unit testing Twilio SMS.

I solved the issue by registering [JavaTimeModule](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) on the ObjectMapper.

```
        String json = "{\"status\": \"sent\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        var message = Message.fromJson(json, mapper);
```

Comment: Dude, your answer was right on the spot. It fixed the issue.

Comment: incompatible types: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModul
e cannot be converted to org.testcontainers.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module

Comment: This is the correct way to solve the issue. Other suggestions about opening java.base/java.time or writing a custom adapter should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after upgrading the application to Java 17 and Spring Boot 3. Adding VM options will lead to other problems.

1.Fixed by adding the adapter.

```
 public class LocalDateTypeAdapter
    implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

  private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(final LocalDate date, final Type typeOfSrc,
      final JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(date.format(formatter));
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
      final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return LocalDate.parse(json.getAsString(), formatter);
  }
}
```

2.Then register the adapter like this :-

```
@Configuration
public class GsonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public GsonBuilderCustomizer typeAdapterRegistration() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateTypeAdapter());
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about Jackson, though, not Gson. Jackson is the preferred default in Spring Boot. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.json

Answer (score 0):

You can always use additional DTO object with already parsed LocalDate to String.

Answer (score -12):

I solved this problem to change jdk16 to jdk11.

Comment: You haven't solved it.  You have just put off the problem so that it can come back and bite you when you move to Java 17 (or later).