# How can i use the --add-opens flag in heroku

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

i want to run the -- add-opens command in an application i distribute in every arrow, but i don't know where to add it in the cloud when i know where to add it in local

"Could not read JSON: Unable to make field private final int java.time.LocalDate.year accessible"

i was getting the error and

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70412805/what-does-this-error-mean-java-lang-reflect-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable"

i've come to a solution with this method, but now i want to deploy my project on every arrow, but i don't know how to report the add-open command to my application on the server, i tried to add it as a procfile and environment variable, but it didn't

(the application is crashed when i set the command to the environment variable)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question with as much detail as possible.

Comment: Also, make a [mre] by showing your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I made a mistake in procfile's commands

Before:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Then:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dserver.port=$PORT --add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED -jar target/*.jar
```