# Failed making field 'property' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type, gSON fromJson

Tags: java, gson

I have a class called Game:

```
public class Game {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private GameFields[] gameFields;

    @Expose(deserialize = false)
    public ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public Game() {

    }

    public Game(String name, int id, GameFields[] gameFields) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.gameFields = gameFields;
    }
}
```

and I want to make Objects for this class with the GSON.fromJson method.
but the problem is the method returns

```
Failed to make field 'com.example.Models.Game#name' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type
```

this is how I call the method

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Game object = null;
try {
    object = gson.fromJson("{\"name\":\"test\",\"id\":1}", Game.class);
}catch (JsonParseException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I don't know why this is happening, because in every example I saw, users used private visibility for their fields.
but in my case, it works only when I change the visibility of my fields to Public.

**UPDATE**

entire stack trace :

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'com.example.server.Models.Game#name' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:22)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:158)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:101)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:501)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:990)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:956)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:905)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:876)
    at com.example.server/com.example.server.Server$2.onData(Server.java:55)
    at com.example.server/com.example.server.Server$2.onData(Server.java:44)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.namespace.Namespace.onEvent(Namespace.java:146)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.PacketListener.onPacket(PacketListener.java:106)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.InPacketHandler.channelRead0(InPacketHandler.java:92)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.InPacketHandler.channelRead0(InPacketHandler.java:36)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.transport.PollingTransport.onPost(PollingTransport.java:161)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.transport.PollingTransport.handleMessage(PollingTransport.java:120)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.transport.PollingTransport.channelRead(PollingTransport.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at netty.socketio@1.7.18/com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.AuthorizeHandler.channelRead(AuthorizeHandler.java:137)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:316)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String com.example.server.Models.Game.name accessible: module com.example.server does not "opens com.example.server.Models" to module com.google.gson
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
    at com.google.gson@2.9.0/com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:19)
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: They probably omitted getter/setter for the fields, which are needed to expose the fields to other classes. Or they used lombok library with `@Getter` / `@Setter`

Comment: I have no issues at all with the above code. Gson uses field access so adding getters is simply not required. Also, fields are allowed to be private as it uses Reflection. Please post the whole stack trace, not only the message.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle i added the stack trace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by adding the line :

```
opens com.example.server.Models to com.google.gson;
```

to `module-info.java`

Comment: This is applicable to java 11 and above

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with deserializing java.time.Instant with gson during java upgrade version 11 to 17, Please refer the gson documentation sheds light on why it happens:
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/UserGuide.md#gsons-expose

**Solution:**
create Gson by using- `new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()`

example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create();
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with deserializing java.time.LocalDate with gson, and I think this part of the gson documentation sheds light on why it happens:

[Gson documentation troubleshooting](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/Troubleshooting.md#inaccessibleobjectexception-module--does-not-opens--to-unnamed-module)

I am quoting from the documentation:

> Explanation: When no built-in adapter for a type exists and no custom
> adapter has been registered, Gson falls back to using reflection to
> access the fields of a class (including private ones). Most likely you
> are seeing this error because you (by accident) rely on the
> reflection-based adapter for third-party classes. That should be
> avoided because you make yourself dependent on the implementation
> details of these classes which could change at any point. For the JDK
> it is also not possible anymore to access internal fields using
> reflection starting with JDK 17, see JEP 403. If you want to prevent
> using reflection on third-party classes in the future you can write
> your own ReflectionAccessFilter or use one of the predefined ones,
> such as ReflectionAccessFilter.BLOCK_ALL_PLATFORM.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `Gson` might not be able to translate `Arraylists` from your class to json strings. So, that's why it is recommending type adapters. Type adapters are basically used to translate classes which gson won't be able to translate to json otherwise. In this adapter you would describe how your class should be converted to/from a json string. Here's the [doc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)

Also, ["{"name":"test","id":1}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72769462/failed-making-field-property-accessible-either-change-its-visibility-or-write#:%7E:text=%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%5C%22test%5C%22%2C%5C%22id%5C%22%3A1%7D%22) doesn't have the arraylist `GameFields`. So, that's another point of error possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with more complex class that included several objects that were involved into deserialization. The issue was resolved by marking explicitly which fields of the classes are involved in deserialization with [`@Expose`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/UserGuide.md#gsons-expose) annotation.

Also `@SerializedName` annotation is used for each field for mapping between fields and JSON elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post what perfectly worked for me in my similar erroneous scenario. I created the `customGson` that resolved my issue & have demonstrated the use of the same just below it.

```
Gson customGson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateTypeAdapter())
    .create();

// Consider this as your request POJO which is not null
MemberSearchRequestPojo requestPojo; 
String jsonRequestString = customGson.toJson(requestPojo);

// Consider `responseJsonString` this as the JSON string that contains the response to be converted to a POJO

// Consider MemberSearchResponsePojo as your response POJO
MemberSearchResponsePojo responsePojo = customGson.fromJson(responseJsonString, MemberSearchResponsePojo.class);
```

`LocalDateTypeAdapter` needs to be separately defined which is your custom TypeAdapter & is referenced above while creating the custom GSON object which can be done as follows:

```
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class LocalDateTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate>, JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

  private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(final LocalDate date, final Type typeOfSrc,
      final JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(date.format(formatter));
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
      final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return LocalDate.parse(json.getAsString(), formatter);
  }
}
```

1. [Reference Link-1](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2485)
2. [Reference Link-2](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-typeadapter-for-inaccessibleobjectexception/)
3. [Reference Link-3](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/wa0d3g/help_with_using_gson_to_convert_simple_json/)

This solution from `Reference Link-2` is worked for me.
You can try the `module-info.java` file solution approach as well, but unfortunately I could not make that work for me.