# Junit test case causing JsonIOException for java.time.ZonedDateTime#dateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am facing same issue as mentioned here in the following question  [Failed making field 'property' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type, gSON fromJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72769462/failed-making-field-property-accessible-either-change-its-visibility-or-write)
but for a inbuilt class java.time.ZonedDateTime#dateTime. and i dont have module-info as my application is migrated from java 8 to java 11. This is happening while running a junit test case which uses ZonedDateTime object. please let me know how can I overcome the issue. complete trace

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.time.ZonedDateTime#dateTime' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
at app//com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:287)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
at app//com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:546)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:366)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:183)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:70)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
at app//com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:144)
at app//com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:825)
at app//com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:795)
at app//com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:742)
at app//com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:719)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1850)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$15$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:541)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.time.LocalDateTime java.time.ZonedDateTime.dateTime accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @58ceff1
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35)
... 114 more

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while serializing an object with an attribute java.time.Instant using Gson when upgrading java from version 11 to 17.

This issue answer explains why this happens: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1979#issuecomment-927943566

Solution: create Gson by using- new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()

example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create();
```

(this answer was adapted from [Praveen Kumar Verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4673240/praveen-kumar-verma)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357819/4326295))